# Why does three functions with same name works only once?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why this is?

I'm trying to make it possible to hide any of the three areas by clicking on the respective button.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="prod">Prod

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="prodButton">Hide</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("prod").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  </script>
</div>
<div id="test">Test

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="testButton">Hide</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  </script>
</div>
<div id="dev">Dev

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="devButton">Hide</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: it only works once because you're calling the same function 3 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do this:

```
function myFunction() {
```

You are apparently **redefining the function** (killing the old function and creating a new one, so that the **last one only wins**). You need to make it in such a way that it accepts an argument and based on that it should do something. You are **misusing** or not getting the concept of functions.

Ultimately your function should look like:

```
function myFunction(element) {
  document.getElementById(element).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Defined just once and it should be called multiple times, like below:

```
myFunction("prod");
myFunction("test");
myFunction("dev");
```

**Full Code**

```
<script>
  function myFunction(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
</script>
<div id="prod">Prod
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(\"prod\")" class="prodButton">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="test">Test
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(\"test\")" class="testButton">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="dev">Dev
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(\"dev\")" class="devButton">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. It wouldn't work at first so I changed the bottom part to this:

Comment: <div id="prod">Prod
                        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('prod')" class="prodButton">Hide</button>
                      </div>
                      <div id="test">Test
                        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('test')" class="testButton">Hide</button>
                      </div>
                      <div id="dev">Dev
                        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('dev')" class="devButton">Hide</button>
                      </div>

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just test out some code quickly, then you can write inline javascript code like below. But this should not be written as production code.

```
    <div id="prod">Prod
  <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.visibility='hidden'" class="prodButton">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="test">Test
  <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.visibility='hidden'" class="testButton">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="dev">Dev
  <button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.style.visibility='hidden'" class="devButton">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `But this should not be written as production code. [...]` Yup. Let's do the right thing even in dev... `:)`

Comment: Correct @Praveen. Unless it's not for development ;)